# Match a custom fiducial using boofcv or other java library

Tags: java, image-processing, barcode

I have a custom fiducial that uses a pattern like this to detect orientation.

[image]

The actual data comes inside the fiducial marker. How do I go about matching my fiducial. Right now am using the below method.

1. Using BoofCV library and identifying contours.
2. Iterating through the contours and detecting neighboring contours and checking a pattern exists.
3. If the pattern exists but does not match, the process is repeated till a full match is found.

Is it the right way to go about it?

I do know the size of the fiducial marker.

Comment: There's an excellent black polygon detector in BoofCV. Do you need think lines connecting the squares? If you get rid of those it will be much easier.

Comment: Yes, the thick lines have to be removed and have changed the fiducial structure in such a way that orientation is handled. I used Polygon Detector - Fit Binary Edges work well in most cases and CANNY BINARY works well in certain remote cases not caught by Binary Edges. Will update with the new fiducial structure and the steps involved in deciphering the value.